# How to remove SCNNode from the scene and free up memory in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory-management, scenekit, arkit

RemoveFromParentNode() only removes the node from the parent node/scene but does not remove it from memory as you can still reference the node  after the line is executed.

I'm wondering how we can remove the node completely from memory, setting the node to null has no effect on the variable as you can see from the code below.

Most solutions I've seen are in swift but I can't find a solution in Xamarin.iOS C#

```
var myNode = new SCNNode
{
    Name = "My Node"
};

SView.Scene.RootNode.Add(myNode);

SView.Scene.RootNode.EnumerateChildNodes((SCNNode node, out bool stop) =>
{
    node.RemoveFromParentNode();
    node = null; // Does nothing 

    stop = false;
});

try
{
    Debug.WriteLine(myNode.Name);
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("We already deleted myNode" + ex.Message);
}
```

Expected to reach the catch: "We already deleted myNode".

Actual output: "My Node"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCNode` is a native ObjC object w/ a .Net wrapper on top. When you are assigning it `null` that is only handing the Xamarin.iOS/Mono side of the reference counting. You need to call `Dispose` on it to release those native references.

```
node.Dispose();
```